# unable to update source code using cfn-hup in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to update source code on an EC2 instance using `cfn-hup` service in cloud formation (AWS).

When I update the stack with new source code using build number, the source code does changes at EC2.

`cfn-hup` service running fine and all configurations are OK.

Below are the logs of `cfn-hup`.

```
2016-03-05 08:48:19,912 [INFO] Data has changed from previous state; action for cfn-auto-reloader-hook will be run
2016-03-05 08:48:19,912 [INFO] Running action for cfn-auto-reloader-hook
2016-03-05 08:48:20,191 [WARNING] Action for cfn-auto-reloader-hook exited with 1; will retry on next iteration
```

Can anyone plz help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

The error states `Action for cfn-auto-reloader-hook exited with 1`. This means that the `action` specified in your `cfn-auto-reloader-hook` has been executed, but returned an error code of `1` indicating a failure state. The good news is that everything else is set up correctly (the `cfn-hup` script is installed and running, it correctly detected a metadata change, and it found the `cfn-auto-reloader` hook).

Look at the `action=` line in your `cfn-hup` entry for this hook. A typical hook will look something like this:

```
[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
triggers=post.update
path=Resources.WebServerInstance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
action=some_shell_command_here
runas=root
```

To find the hook, run `cat /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf` on the instance, or trace back where these file contents are defined in your CloudFormation template (e.g., in the [example LAMP stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html), this hook is created by the [`files`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-files) section of an [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) Metadata Resource, used by the [cfn-init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) helper script). Try manually executing the line in a local shell. If it fails, use the relevant output or error logs to continue debugging. Change the command and cfn-hup should succeed the next time it runs.

Comment: I encountered a situation where the exit error is 127, but when running with sudo or under root user, the command works fine. What else could be failing?

Answer (score 0):

This means one of your cfn-init items is failing. If it works the first time, it's likely that you have a commands section item that needs a "test" clause to determine if it needs to run or not.